# scrollTop 'back to top' button does not fade in/out

Tags: jquery

I'm using the code below to show a hidden div (back to top button) once the user has scrolled down 500px. It works fine, but the problem I'm having is that the button does not fade in nor does it fade out.

```
//Back to top
$('.back-to-top').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
    return false;
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 500) {
        $('.back-to-top:hidden').stop(true, true).fadeIn(500);
    } else {
        $('.back-to-top').stop(true, true).fadeOut(500);
    }
});
```

```html
<a href="#" class="back-to-top" style="display:none"><img src="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ); ?>/img/back_to_top.png" width="32"></a>
```

Comment: make a fiddle and update your post

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am a practical guy, so I'm going to give you a practical answer. Apparently the `:hidden` pseudonym on the element and the `true` attributes of the `stop()` function seem to be causing the issue. Removing them seems to be solving the issue. Also, I believe your check for `scrollTop` should be the other way around, if I understood your question correctly.

Below is a test I created; hope this will help you get to the bottom of this.

```js
$('.back-to-top').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
    return false;
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() <= 500) {
        $('.back-to-top').stop().fadeIn(500);
    } else {
        $('.back-to-top').stop().fadeOut(500);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="back-to-top" style="position:fixed; top:0; border: 1px solid red">sadasdasd</a>
<div style="height:1000px; border: 1px solid #000">bla</div>
```

And here it is on jsfiddle, so you can apply modifications if you wanted to play with it: http://jsfiddle.net/aefvamrg/

Answer (score 0):

this is what I use..

http://jsfiddle.net/1ktksqqs/

```
<style>
#back-top {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 30px;
}
#back-top a {
    width: 108px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center !important;
    font: 11px/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #bbb;
    /* background color transition */
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    -moz-transition: 1s;
    transition: 1s;
}
#back-top a:hover {
    color: #000;
}
#back-top span {
    width: 108px;
    height: 108px;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    background: #ddd url("http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-46DxhA_q6LE/UnI5YBGzCfI/AAAAAAAABP8/IC6g6GwkQlY/s1600/back-to-top+gray.png") no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    -moz-transition: 1s;
    transition: 1s;
}
#back-top a:hover span {
    background-color: #777;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#back-top").hide();
    jQuery(function () {
        jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
        if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 400) {
                jQuery('#back-top').fadeIn();
        } else {
                jQuery('#back-top').fadeOut();
        }
    });
    // scroll body to 0px on click
    jQuery('#back-top a').click(function () {
        jQuery('body,html').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 800);
            return false;
        });
    });
 });
 </script>
 <p id="back-top"><a href="#top"><span></span>Back to Top</a></p>
```